# How to customize stylelint for scss

Tags: css, sass, eslint, stylelint

I am unable to customize the stylelint for my project. I want to get the style code like in the example:

```
.s{

  .f{
      width:2px;
   }

  .d{
     width:2px;
    }

}
```

But when using this rule: `"block-closing-brace-empty-line-before": "always-multi-line"`

My code have this style:

```
.s{

  .f{
      width:2px;

   }

  .d{
     width:2px;

    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe show your html as an example ?

Comment: Why? I geted example how it should be my style code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the rule's](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/block-closing-brace-empty-line-before) [`"except": ["after-closing-brace"]`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/block-closing-brace-empty-line-before/#except-after-closing-brace) secondary option with the `"never"` primary option to achieve this code style, e.g.:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "block-closing-brace-empty-line-before": [
      "never", {
        "except": ["after-closing-brace"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This rule work for function such as @media, but me need for  classes which nested, how as in the example above